# how do I put label span and input in same line

Tags: html, input, line, formgroups

If I dont put span tag then all is ok, but when the add span tag `<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lira-sign"></i></span>` then input and span not on the same line.

how can I solve only with bootstrap class.

```
<div class="form-group-sm row">
  <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label text-right">Şifre:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-9 input-group-sm row">
    <div>
      <input value="" type="number" class="form-control" name="alt_toplam_kdvsiz" id="alt_toplam_kdvsiz" placeholder="" readonly>
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lira-sign"></i></span>
  </div>
    
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap class `input-group-text` transform elements into flexbox, which forces your span to wrap. If you can somehow set property `display` to value `inline` it should fix your problem.
For example:

```
<span class="input-group-text" style="display: inline"><i class="fas fa-lira-sign"></i></span>
```